# awk | Rearrange fields of CSV file on the basis of column value

Tags: awk

I need you help in writing awk for the below problem. I have one source file and required output of it.

Source File

> a:5,b:1,c:2,session:4,e:8
>   b:3,a:11,c:5,e:9,session:3,c:3

Output File

> session:4,a=5,b=1,c=2
>   session:3,a=11,b=3,c=5|3

Notes:

- Fields are not organised in source file
- In Output file: fields are organised in their specific format, for example: all a values are in 2nd column and then b and then c
- For value c, in second line, its coming as n number of times, so in output its merged with PIPE symbol.

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware of the `split` function in `awk`? Why did you drop the data for `e:8` in the first line and `e:9` in the second? Is it strictly tags `session`, `a`, `b`, and `c` that should appear in the output? What if one of those is missing?

Comment: I know split as command but not through awk.. But I can try for that if that will help or if you can guide me. "e" data is ignored because I need few fields only out of all. yes, those are tags "session" "a" "b" and "c".. If one of those is missing than I need BLANK value in that.

Comment: RTM ([`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)): `split(s, a[, fs  ])`: _Split the string `s` into array elements `a[1]`, `a[2]`, ..., `a[n]`, and return `n`. All elements of the array shall be deleted before the split is performed. The separation shall be done with the ERE `fs` or with the field separator FS if `fs` is not given. Each array element shall have a string value when created and, if appropriate, the array element shall be considered a numeric string (see Expressions in awk). The effect of a null string as the value of `fs` is unspecified._

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.. I tried with split and succeeded upto some extent but not completly..awk '{split($0,array,","); for (b in array){if (array[b]~/a:/)a=array[b]; if (array[b]~/session:/)session=array[b]} print session","a}' source.log But thanks for your help :)

Comment: Edit the question to show what you've tried...though I see you've accepted an answer.  In general, if you need to clarify the question, and especially if you need to show code, edit the question rather than try using comments.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.. I 'll make sure to follow what you said. But you taught me new function of awk.. so thanks for that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will work in any modern awk:

```
$ cat file
a:5,b:1,c:2,session:4,e:8
a:5,c:2,session:4,e:8
b:3,a:11,c:5,e:9,session:3,c:3

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS="[,:]"; split("session,a,b,c",order) }
{
    split("",val)               # or delete(val) in gawk
    for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) {
        val[$i] = (val[$i]=="" ? "" : val[$i] "|") $(i+1)
    }

    for (i=1;i in order;i++) {
        name = order[i]
        printf "%s%s", (i==1 ? name ":" : "," name "="), val[name]
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
session:4,a=5,b=1,c=2
session:4,a=5,b=,c=2
session:3,a=11,b=3,c=5|3
```

If you actually want the `e` values printed, unlike your posted desired output, just add `,e` to the string in the `split()` in the BEGIN section wherever you'd like those values to appear in the ordered output.

Note that when `b` was missing from the input on line 2 above, it output a null value as you said you wanted.

Comment: HEllo Ed again.. Is it possible to print "|" pipe value for some specific fields only? For exmaple: I want pipe only for value"c" and "b" and not for "a"

Comment: Of course, just list whatever fields you want in the `split("session,a,b,c",order)` which creates the array named `order[]` of the fields you want, in order. So you'd just change that statement to `split("session,b,c",order)`.

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
awk '
    BEGIN  { 
        FS = "[,:]"
        OFS = ","
    }
    {
        for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i+= 2 ) {
            if ( $i == "session" ) { printf "%s:%s", $i, $(i+1); continue }
            hash[$i] = hash[$i] (hash[$i] ? "|" : "") $(i+1)
        }

        asorti( hash, hash_orig )
        for ( i = 1; i <= length(hash); i++ ) {
            printf ",%s:%s", hash_orig[i], hash[ hash_orig[i] ]
        }
        printf "\n"
        delete hash
        delete hash_orig
    }
' infile
```

that splits line with any comma or colon and traverses all odd fields to save either them and its values in a hash to print at the end. It yields:

```
session:4,a:5,b:1,c:2,e:8
session:3,a:11,b:3,c:5|3,e:9
```

Comment: You should mention it's gawk-specific courtesy of delete(array), length(array), and asorti(). Also, I think if you change `c:5` to `c:0` in the input then `(hash[$i] ? "|" : "")` won't behave as desired. I also don't think it will print a null value if `b` is missing from the input, for example.